# Google Sign IN in android application

Tags: android, google-api-client, android-developer-api

How can I do google sign in my android application without using google plus .
I need sign in of google in my app is like we sign in like facebook that a screen is appeared that ask you to fill username and password and then click on sign in button.

I had sign directly by using google play library and but I want that prompt comes and ask for the username and password .

I got a problem using google plus is that if any body had a google account but not activated its google plus account then what can I do in that case?

I want google sign in that way is there any way please give me solutions as soon as possible .

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use following approach: First of all, ask user to enter email Id say in editText and get that value on click of some button, and proceed like below:

```
//Check whether account is already configured or not


        if(isAccountAlreadyConfigured(emailId)){
    //If the email id entered by user is already configured in the device
                                getGoogleApiClientInstance(emailId);
                                connectToGoogleApiClient();
                            }else{
    //If that email id account is not configured in the device
                                Bundle accountOptions = new Bundle();
                                accountOptions.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, emailId);
                                accountOptions.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE,Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                                accountManager.addAccount(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null, null, accountOptions, this, accountManagerCallback, null);
                            }

        /* @method isAccountAlreadyConfigured is used to check whether the email address entered by user is already
             * configured in the device or not
             * @param String: it takes the email address as the parameter
             * @return boolean*/
            private boolean isAccountAlreadyConfigured(String accountName){
                Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                for(Account account: accounts ){
                        if(account.name.equals(accountName)){
//Account alreadyConfiguredAccount = account; //Use this for confirmCredentialsMethod
                            return true;
                        }
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Account info: "+account.name + "\n" + "Account type: "+account.type);
                }
                return false;
            }

        /* @method getGoogleApiClientInstance is used to get GoogleApiClientInstance for a particular google account
             * @Param String : gmail account Id
             * @return GoogleApiClient instance 
             * */
            private GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClientInstance(String accountName){
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .setAccountName(accountName)
                .build();

                return mGoogleApiClient;
            }

        /* @method connectToGoogleApiClient is used to connect GoogleApiClient instance to Google API servers */
                private void connectToGoogleApiClient(){            

                    if(mGoogleApiClient != null){
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    }else{
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting google api client");
                    }       
                }

    /* accountManagerCallback is used to pass as one of  the params to AccountManager.addAccount method*/
        private AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> accountManagerCallback = new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

            @Override
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                futureBundle = future;
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Done: " +future.isDone() + "\n" + "isCancelled: "+future.isCancelled());        
                handler.post(runnable);
            }
        };

        private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

            try {
                // futureBundle.getResult() call will block until the result is available so we call it on another thread
                Bundle bundle = futureBundle.getResult();
                if(bundle != null){
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Result: "+bundle);
                    String authAccount = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    String accountType = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE);

                    /*Result bundle should have authAccount and accountType as the extras, this acts as a confirmation that
                      the account is properly configured in the device or we can cross verify by calling
                      @method isAccountAlreadyConfigured*/ 
                    if((authAccount.equals(emailId) && accountType.equals(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE)) || isAccountAlreadyConfigured(emailId)){
                        getGoogleApiClientInstance(emailId);
                        connectToGoogleApiClient();
                    }else{              
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "An error occured while configuring new account");
                    }
                }           
            } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {        
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {       
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
        };
```

Or you can use below code if you don't want to use GoogleApiClient instance for already configured account ie. above if

```
if(isAccountAlreadyConfigured(emailId)){
 Bundle accountOptions = new Bundle();
                            accountOptions.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, emailId);
                            accountOptions.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE,"com.google");
                            accountManager.confirmCredentials(account, accountOptions, this, accountManagerCallback, null);
}
```

First parameter account is of type Account class which you can retrieve from isAccountAlreadyConfiguredMethod.

Comment: hey i was not able to do that ? can you help me

Comment: What is the problem  that you are facing? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: it gives me a null pointer exception and some of the variables i m not able to understand how to use them and please let me know as soon as possible

Comment: Which variables you are not able to understand and where are you getting null pointer exception? Kindly provide detailed log so that I can help you out.

Comment: can i  get your email id so that i can ask you ques there if you don't mind @namrata-bagerwal 

my email id is maheshsingh.singh8@gmail.com thanks for my help

Answer (score 0):

**Dependency**
    **Need Internet Permission**

**Working Code   see Link on  play Store**
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=com.codecube.airbucks

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:id="@+id/btn"/>
</LinearLayout>

package com.keshav.geofencing;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Arrays;

import utilities.CommonMethod;
import utilities.LoginPreferences;


public class LoginWithGmail extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    Button loginSub;
    LinearLayout signInButton;


    String gmailId;
    String gmailName;
    String gmailUserEmailId;
    Uri gmailUserPhoto;
    String savePassword;
    LinearLayout btnlogin;
    TextView btnsigning;
    ProgressDialog prgDialog;

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    private LinearLayout fbloginButton;
//    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    EditText edtEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login1);

        checkPermission();

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();


        // Google Sign up Button
        signInButton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginWithGmail.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                    if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        //showing dialog to select image

                        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                        signInIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
                        Log.e("permission", "granted");
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginWithGmail.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                    signInIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public void checkPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginWithGmail.this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

            if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //showing dialog to select image
                if (CommonMethod.isNetworkAvailable(LoginWithGmail.this)) {
                    Log.e("keshav", "Permission if part marsh");
                } else {
                    CommonMethod.showAlert("Internet Connectivity Failure", LoginWithGmail.this);
                }

                Log.e("keshav", "permission granted");
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginWithGmail.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
//        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
//                new IntentFilter(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    // TODO ADD ME

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
            // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
            Log.e(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
            // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
            // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // [START signOut]
    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
//                        updateUI(false);
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END signOut]

    // [START revokeAccess]
    private void revokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
//                        updateUI(false);
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END revokeAccess]

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
        if (LoginWithGmail.this != null && mProgressDialog != null && !mProgressDialog.equals("null"))
            mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()&& !mProgressDialog.equals("null")) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }


    // TODO ADD ME ENd


    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.e("&&&s", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            gmailId = acct.getId();
            gmailName = acct.getDisplayName();
            gmailUserEmailId = acct.getEmail();
            gmailUserPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();

            Log.e("gmailId", "is -->" + gmailId);
            Log.e("gmailName", "is -->" + gmailName);
            Log.e("gmailUserEmailId", "is -->" + gmailUserEmailId);
            Log.e("gmailUserPhoto", "is -->" + gmailUserPhoto);

            LoginPreferences.getActiveInstance(LoginWithGmail.this).setUserName(gmailName);
            LoginPreferences.getActiveInstance(LoginWithGmail.this).setProfileImage(""+gmailUserPhoto);


            Log.e("information", "using Gmail is > " + gmailId + " " + gmailName + "" + gmailUserEmailId + "" + gmailUserPhoto);

            if (CommonMethod.isNetworkAvailable(LoginWithGmail.this)) {
                Log.e("SignUp gmail", "Hit API..........................");
                Intent i=new Intent(LoginWithGmail.this,DrawerActivity.class);
                LoginPreferences.getActiveInstance(LoginWithGmail.this).setIsLoggedIn(true);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

                // TODO Here Registered User in own Database call Volley Retrofit2 Api ....
                new SignUpSocialFacebookAsyncTask().execute();
            } else {
                CommonMethod.showAlert("Intenet Connectivity Failure", LoginWithGmail.this);
            }

        } else {

        }
        // TODO ADD ME KESHAV Google GMail Logout
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Login Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.keshav.geofencing/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(mGoogleApiClient, viewAction);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    //Todo  add new method for permission
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            signInIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

        }
    }

}

**Dependency**
**Need Internet Permission**
```

**Working Code   see Link on  play Store**
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=com.codecube.airbucks

Please Like this post if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
on adding 
  Bundle accountOptions = new Bundle();
                                accountOptions.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, emailId);  
accountOptions.putString(AccountManager.KEY_PASSWORD, password);
                                accountOptions.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE,Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                                accountManager.addAccount(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null, null, accountOptions, this, accountManagerCallback, null);
```